# How to add a program to Cairo Dock

Tags: dock, cairo

I want to add VLC and other programs to the Cairo Dock but I don't know how. I have accidentally removed Terminal from the dock and I want to get it back.

I am using Gnome Desktop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add a program, just right click on the dock, and click on Cairo-Dock --> Add --> Custom launcher.  Once the new window opens, just fill in the needed info, and click apply.  See images below.

[image]

[image]

See the new program added to the Dock

[image]

Comment: The interface lacks button for the search window for executable where command to launch resides( 
You still have to cram it char by char, no drag-n-drop.

Comment: how this is marked as an answer? there is no example and this answer doesn't even tell what cmd need to paste.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you are using Ubuntu with Unity.

To add any program just search for it in dash and then drag and drop it to the dock.

You can also rearrange items in dock by drag and drop.

Comment: No I'm using Gnome Desktop

Comment: I m also on Gnome and it is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry in advance for not including images.  I have not been able to drag and drop items from the dashboard.  However, if you open the application from the dash it will automatically appear on the cairo dock.  You can then right click the app on the dock, mouse over the application name, and select 'make it a launcher'. Boom.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! You will not be able to add pictures until you reach a higher reputation level.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the app in the **Desktop first and then drag it into the Dock**.

Works for me in Linux Mint 19 "Tara" (Cinnamon)

Comment: You need to add it to desktop first.

Comment: that's what I said..

Comment: This is way simpler that fishing program icons and typing the executable name. Thanks! Works on Linux Mint Cinnamon 22.04.